# USB Wifi no available hardware connection

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers, usb, kernel-modules

Just received a USB Wifi adapter Tp-Link Archer T4U and it is not shown in the available network connections. Running Fedora 35.

```
# lsusb -v -d 2357:0115

Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link Archer T4U ver.3
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2357 TP-Link
  idProduct          0x0115 Archer T4U ver.3
  bcdDevice            2.10
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 802.11ac NIC
  iSerial                 3 123456
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0035
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           5
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 802.11ac NIC
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      HIRD Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0006
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat        1023 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

```
# nmcli device status
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
enp4s0f0u3  ethernet  connected               Wired connection 1
virbr0      bridge    connected (externally)  virbr0
enp6s0      ethernet  unavailable             --
lo          loopback  unmanaged               --
```

The Linux driver file for [download](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201806/20180619/Archer%20T4U(EUUS)_V3_180511_Linux.zip) in the TP-Link site is the `Archer T4U(EUUS)_V3_180511_Linux.zip`. Inside that zip file there is the `rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.1_22719.20170613_COEX20170518-4444_AddLED` directory. And inside it the `rtl8822b.mk` file.

I tried to compile it but got some errors. I'm confused about what driver should be loaded. What I have is:

```
# ll /usr/lib/modules/5.16.14-200.fc35.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  28 Mar 11 17:47 rtl818x
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  28 Mar 16 06:27 rtl8xxxu
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 294 Mar 16 06:27 rtlwifi
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 342 Mar 16 06:27 rtw88
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  62 Mar 16 06:27 rtw89

# ll /usr/lib/modules/5.16.14-200.fc35.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/
total 84
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 84472 Mar 11 17:58 rtl8xxxu.ko.xz
```

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
isofs                  49152  0
rndis_host             20480  0
cdc_ether              24576  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 53248  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
rfcomm                 90112  0
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  3
xt_conntrack           16384  1
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_nat_tftp            16384  0
nft_objref             16384  1
nf_conntrack_tftp      20480  3 nf_nat_tftp
nft_fib_inet           16384  1
nft_fib_ipv4           16384  1 nft_fib_inet
nft_fib_ipv6           16384  1 nft_fib_inet
nft_fib                16384  3 nft_fib_ipv6,nft_fib_ipv4,nft_fib_inet
nft_reject_inet        16384  7
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  2 nft_reject_inet,ipt_REJECT
nf_reject_ipv6         20480  1 nft_reject_inet
nft_reject             16384  1 nft_reject_inet
nft_ct                 20480  26
nft_chain_nat          16384  2
ip6table_nat           16384  1
ip6table_mangle        16384  1
ip6table_raw           16384  0
ip6table_security      16384  0
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat                 57344  5 ip6table_nat,nf_nat_tftp,nft_chain_nat,iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack          163840  6 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_tftp,nft_ct,nf_nat_tftp,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_raw            16384  0
iptable_security       16384  0
bridge                335872  0
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
ip_set                 61440  0
nf_tables             262144  340 nft_ct,nft_reject_inet,nft_fib_ipv6,nft_objref,nft_fib_ipv4,nft_chain_nat,nft_reject,nft_fib,nft_fib_inet
nfnetlink              20480  3 nf_tables,ip_set
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             36864  5 ip6table_filter,ip6table_raw,ip6table_nat,ip6table_mangle,ip6table_security
iptable_filter         16384  1
qrtr                   45056  4
bnep                   28672  2
sunrpc                659456  1
vfat                   20480  1
fat                    86016  1 vfat
nvidia_drm             73728  21
nvidia_modeset       1163264  35 nvidia_drm
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
nvidia_uvm           1191936  0
edac_mce_amd           36864  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   155648  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
btusb                  65536  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
kvm_amd               147456  0
snd_hda_intel          57344  4
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
pktcdvd                49152  0
uvcvideo              122880  0
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
snd_usb_audio         352256  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         172032  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
snd_usbmidi_lib        45056  1 snd_usb_audio
nvidia              39112704  1879 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
kvm                  1028096  1 kvm_amd
snd_hda_core          110592  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
btintel                45056  1 btusb
snd_seq                86016  7 snd_seq_dummy
videobuf2_v4l2         36864  1 uvcvideo
rapl                   20480  0
bluetooth             692224  16 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
videobuf2_common       69632  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
snd_seq_device         16384  2 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi
snd_pcm               139264  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
videodev              266240  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     65536  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_timer              45056  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
drm_kms_helper        315392  1 nvidia_drm
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
pcspkr                 16384  0
gigabyte_wmi           20480  0
rfkill                 28672  6 bluetooth
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd                   110592  31 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
k10temp                16384  0
i2c_piix4              28672  0
cec                    69632  1 drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
gpio_amdpt             20480  0
gpio_generic           16384  1 gpio_amdpt
acpi_cpufreq           28672  0
drm                   634880  25 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
zram                   28672  2
ip_tables              36864  5 iptable_filter,iptable_security,iptable_raw,iptable_nat,iptable_mangle
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  7
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
hid_logitech_dj        28672  0
nvme                   49152  3
sp5100_tco             20480  0
r8169                  98304  0
ccp                   106496  1 kvm_amd
nvme_core             139264  4 nvme
wmi                    32768  2 gigabyte_wmi,wmi_bmof
vfio_pci               16384  0
vfio_pci_core          69632  1 vfio_pci
irqbypass              16384  2 vfio_pci_core,kvm
vfio_virqfd            16384  1 vfio_pci_core
vfio_iommu_type1       40960  0
vfio                   45056  2 vfio_pci_core,vfio_iommu_type1
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       118784  1 ipmi_devintf
fuse                  167936  3
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same problem I downloaded the driver from https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU.

The driver from TP-Link only compiles in kernels < 4.15

Comment: FYI, I've also had good results on Fedora from using [aircrack-ng/rtl8812au](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au "Link to AirCrack-NG/rtl8812au driver source on GitHub -->"), although not for your specific device, nor kernel version.